# Can we filter Columns in Select query using Datastax Accessor?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

With Datastax java driver for cassandrausing @Accessor for select query, Can we filter columns in query itself instead of **select *** always

All the examples and docs I see select all the columns.

For example

Select column_A from table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [this](https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/2.1.7/features/object_mapper/using/#accessors) example you have query under your hand. There is a * and you can change it to whatever you like. So you can change * to `column_A` only but pay attention that class under mapping must have same structure. Of course it must be valid CQL query with all partition and clustering columns.

So let's say that you need only `first_name` of `User` class. You would create `User` class with only `first_name` property and Accessor which is using mapped class under the hood will map only `first_name` property and you will get list of `User` objects with single property.

Good way to do it if you sometimes need full object and sometimes only handful of properties would be to create some kind of light mapper objects with subset of properties and use it where needed.

Comment: Do we need to add `@Table`, `@Column` etc annotations to light mapper class? If yes, is it allowed to have 2 classes with same `@Table` annotation?